# Number of days between two Ajax Datetime picker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two Ajax date time picker in my aspx picker.I want to have in script that can count number of days between two dates and paste the number of days in "Number_Of_Days" text box using the java-script  without page refresh.On selection of date from second date it should calculate the number of days at the same time it should check whether date from first datetime picker is picked .

Comment: Are you using jquery ui Date picker?

Comment: No Ajax DateTimePicker in Asp.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
FROM:
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="dateFrom" 
    runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender 
    ID="ajxCEFrom" 
    runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="dateFrom"
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged="calcDays"/>
TO:
<asp:TextBox 
ID="dateTo" 
runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender 
    ID="ajxCETo" 
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="dateTo"
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged="calcDays"/> 
<div>
    DIFFERENCE: <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

and use this code for your javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcDays() {
    var d1 = document.getElementById("<%=dateFrom.ClientID%>");
    var d2 = document.getElementById("<%=dateTo.ClientID%>");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    if(d1.value != "" && d2.value != ""){
        var dateFrom = new Date(d1.value);
        var dateTo = new Date(d2.value);
        var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var diffDays = Math.abs((dateFrom.getTime() - dateTo.getTime()) / (oneDay));
        result.innerHTML = diffDays + " day/s apart.";
    }
}
</script>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Drew for the reply.Looking at the code seems works fine but i am getting small error at **The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).**.Please help me out of this Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you set your control's ClientIDMode to static? if so you can use your control's ID instead of the ClientID.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a library like sugar js, http://sugarjs.com/api/Date/unitsUntil. It has some pretty handy features for dealing with dates and such.